# Pandas - load xml elements as strings

Tags: python, pandas, xml

I'm having trouble with Pandas' `read_xml()` function, where column data is automatically converted to float but I need it as string.

I am opening file from zip and it works fine, but values of the column `'ID'` which contains ids are treated as floats. I need these values to be string because they may start with 0 (or multiple 0s).

This is my code responsible for loading data into dataframe.

```
with zip_file.open(filename) as xml:
    dataframe = pd.read_xml(xml, xpath='//ITEM', encoding='Windows-1250', elems_only=True)
```

`read_xml()` doesn't seem to support dtype parameter and 0s in from the beginning of ids are lost when converting values later. Python version 3.9.

Comment: In forthcoming Pandas 1.5, `read_xml` will now have [dtype and converters](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.5.0.html#read-xml-now-supports-dtype-converters-and-parse-dates) like other IO methods.

Comment: In the meantime, you can run XSLT to [add quotes to your leading zero node values](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/43567#issuecomment-922312397). Post XML for demo. And you can run XSLT 1.0 since your attempted code shows you have `lxml` installed.